# inserting dynamic fields into a database

Tags: php, mysql

i am looking to insert dynamic forms into the data base using the code below

this code at the current stage works but on only shows the one array on the php script how can i make it show both arrays to insert into the database

my form captures a number alias and the number itself - Fax - 00 000 000 how can i display this in the FOR loop at the current stage it only shows 00 000 000

```
<form method='post' action='address.php'>   
<div class="field_wrapper">
<div>
    <input type="text" name="number_alias[]" value="" placeholder='Alias'/>
    <input type="text" name="number_number[]" value="" placeholder='Number'/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"> Add </a>
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit">
</form>


$field_values_array = $_REQUEST['number_number'];
foreach($field_values_array as $value)
{
echo $value . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $field_aliases_array = $_REQUEST['number_number'];
  $field_values_array = $_REQUEST['number_alias'];
  foreach($field_values_array as $index => $value)
  {
    echo $field_aliases_array[$index] . ' : ' . $value . "<br>";
  }
```

Comment: is there a better method for doing this as in providing one array from the html form

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You want to make the inputs a single array? You could have the users input the data into one field, like fax:123-456-7890, or combine the 2 fields into one with javascript, and then submit them, and split the data on the server side, but why? Technically, the $_POST array IS just one array...